# Initializing a 2D array of union type (ints or chars)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d, unions

So I'm trying to create a 2d array of size rows x columns. I allocated space for it (or at least I think) and now I am trying to initialize it or at least test it to see if it can hold values. However I get an incompatible type error whenever I enter either a int or char that the union should hold both.

I think something is wrong with my union, in how I am trying to declare a matrix within a struct because my error says it doesn't recognize my type Mine to hold either ints or chars....or I am just putting values into the 2D array incorrectly.

I'm just trying to right now test and make sure I am making the 2D array correctly pretty much.

ERROR

```
test.c:49:29: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Mine’ from type ‘int’
  myBoard->boardSpaces[0][0] = 5;
```

CODE

```
typedef union
{
    int ajacentMines;
    char mineHere;
}Mine;

typedef struct boards
{
    int rows, columns; //rows and columns to make the array
    Mine **boardSpaces; //a void pointer to hold said array
}Board;

Board *createBoard(int rows, int columns)
{
    Board *b = malloc(sizeof(Board));
    b->rows = rows;
    b->columns = columns;
    b->boardSpaces = malloc(rows*sizeof(Mine*)); //allocate first dimmension 

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        b->boardSpaces[i] = malloc(columns*sizeof(Mine)); //allocate second dimmension

    return b;
}
int main()
{

    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 4;

    Board *myBoard = createBoard(rows,columns);
    myBoard->boardSpaces[0][0] = 5;
    printf("DONE\n");
}
```

Comment: Now when you say *union should hold both*, that's the first problem here. unions store *either*, not *both*. So you can't store *both* the adjacentMines and mineHere. When you put a value to adjacentMines, mineHere will also be modified. Unless there can be no adjacent mines, you should be using `struct` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myBoard->boardSpaces[0][0]` is of type `Mine`, not `int` or `char`.

If you want to assign an int:

```
myBoard->boardSpaces[0][0].ajacentMines = 5;
```

For a char:

```
myBoard->boardSpaces[0][0].mineHere= '5';
```

A union is multiple interpretations of the same location in memory - but the interpretation to be used must be supplied by code.

Comment: Oh crap...I knew that, how did I not see that. Thank you haha, my mind is just spinning with the end of the semester.